Is there a cmdlet to remove crlf from an extracted field in AD using powershell
I am hoping for some guidance in the following area.  I am extracting data from AD using powershell using the following command:
Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $True} -Properties cn, streetaddress, telephoneNumber `
    | Select-Object @{N='AcctName';E='cn'}, @{N='Address';E='streetaddress'}, @{N='Phone';E='telephoneNumber'} | Export-csv c:\temp\test.csv -NoType

In the address field sometimes, it contains one or more carriage return / line feed (crlf) characters.  This causes problems in trying to import the csv file into a SQL server database table.  I'm wondering if there is a cmdlet or something to either replace or remove crlf characters prior to writing out to the csv file using PowerShell.
As a side note when powershell creates the file I'm not sure what encoding it encodes the file with... maybe that is an issue?

What do you want to replace the crlf with?

A proper csv import with quotes etc should be able to handle cr/lfs just fine, no need to cmdlet them away

crlf might be removed or replaced with ||.   The comment from siggemannen may be right but when I try to import the file with crlf in address field I get errors.  It usually states the number of fields in csv does not match what I expect there to be.  In researching it's because it sees that the crlf  breaks the field into multiple fields.


Preface:

Indeed, field-internal newlines in CSV files are not a problem per se, as long as the fields in question are enclosed in "...", which Export-Csv does ensure.

In terms of character encoding, Export-Csv regrettably defaults to ASCII encoding(!) in Windows PowerShell (the legacy, ships-with-Windows, Windows-only edition of PowerShell whose latest and last version is 5.1), whereas it sensibly defaults to (BOM-less) UTF-8 in PowerShell (Core) 7 (the modern, cross-platform, install-on-demand edition).

Passing -Encoding utf8 to Export-Csv in Windows PowerShell invariably creates UTF-8 files with BOM (in PowerShell 7 you can opt into this behavior with -Encoding utf8BOM); workarounds are needed if that is undesired - see this answer.

PowerShell (Core) 7 commendably defaults to (BOM-less) UTF-8 consistently, whereas Windows PowerShell's default encodings vary wildly by cmdlet - see the bottom section of this answer for background information.





You're already using a calculated property in your code:

@{N='Address';E='streetaddress'} uses a string in the E (short for Expression) entry to refer to the value of a property by that name in the pipeline input object at hand.

In order to use a dynamically determined value instead, as is needed in your case, you need to use a script block ({ ... }, inside of which you can use the automatic $_ variable to refer to the input object at hand; this allows you to perform the desired replacement of field-internal newlines with verbatim ||:


Get-ADUser -Filter 'Enabled -eq $True' -Properties cn, streetaddress, telephoneNumber | 
  Select-Object @{N='AcctName';E='cn'}, 
                @{N='Address';E={ $_.streetaddress -replace '\r?\n', '||' }, 
                @{N='Phone';E='telephoneNumber'} | 
  Export-csv c:\temp\test.csv -NoType

Note:

For robustness, the above uses -replace, the regex-based string-replacement operator with regex \r?\n to match both Windows-format CRLF and Unix-format LF-only newlines; however, if you can assume that all newlines to be replaced are CRLF ones, you can use the (more efficient) .NET .Replace() method:
$_.streetaddress.Replace("`r`n", '||')


You can use a calculated expression on Select-Object
    | Select-Object `
        @{N='AcctName'; E='cn'},
        @{N='Address'; E={ $_.StreetAddress.Replace("`r`n", "||") } },
        @{N='Phone'; E='telephoneNumber'} `


Unfortunately, that didn't seem to change anything.

You need double quotes around the backquote r backquote n.  You don't need a continuation character after a comma.

Force of habit, just in case

Awesome... double quotes worked.  Thanks!
